# Find most recent "tweet" created by all followed users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Rails 3.2, twitter app

Update: Wanted to say that I was looking to randomize my tweets. And found `@instace.shuffle.each` does this quite nicely.

Right now i can display all statuses like so,

`users_controller.rb`

```
def buddies
buddies_ids = current_user.followeds.map(&:id).push(current_user.id)

@ribbits = Ribbit.find_all_by_user_id buddies_ids
```

`/views/users/buddies.html.erb`

```
 <% @ribbits.each do |ribbit| %>

<h3><%= ribbit.user.username %></h3>
   <%= ribbit %>
```

You get the point. While I am unsure where `find_all_by_user_id` comes from, I want to only display the most recent status per followeds user.

Where do I put the magic words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also be able to do it in one line:

```
@ribbits = Ribbit.where('user_id IN (?)', buddies_ids).order('created_at DESC').group(:user_id)
```

Then you can do an each just like before to iterate over and display each status.

Comment: You sir win a lunch on me. I will study this line so I can understand this greatness.

Comment: ma'am... and I'm glad it's working :)  If you want an explanation just let me know.

Comment: So I might want an explanation... it appears heroku/postgres is giving me errors in particular to this line.

Comment: From what my childish eyes can see... yes.

Comment: In specific `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "ribbits.id"` and then it points to the area in my view @ribbits.each etc etc

Comment: So i read some stuff.. and I should either upgrade postgres or deploy somewhere else?

Comment: Ok-- this is long, and I don't have time to walk through it now, but give this a shot - `Ribbit.where("(ribbits.user_id, ribbits.created_at) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) FROM ribbits WHERE user_id IN (?) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC LIMIT 10)", buddies_ids).order("created_at DESC")`

Comment: Although my development en. is screwed up since psql, this works on heroku! again! I.O.U two lunches.

Answer (score 0):

`Ribbit.find_all_by_user_id` is a method created dynamically by Rails. See more in this RailsCast on [dynamic find_by methods](http://railscasts.com/episodes/2-dynamic-find-by-methods?view=asciicast).

Much like `find_all_by_user_id` is a dynamic rails method, so is `find_by_user_id`, which will just find the first one. To find the latest "ribbit", you'd want to write

```
@latest_ribbit = Ribbit.find_by_user_id(user_id, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Edit: I should expand on this a little. `find_all_by_user_id` will accept an array of `user_id` values (eg `buddies ids`), as will any other dynamic `find_all_by...` method. `find_by_user_id` will accept an array of user_ids as well, but it will only return the first qualifying item, not the first qualifying item for each user_id in the array. So if you want a plug-and-play example, replace your `@ribbits =` line with

```
@ribbits = []
buddies_ids.each do |id|
  @ribbits << Ribbit.find_by_user_id(user_id, :order => 'created_at DESC')
end
```

You will then need to do some sorting based on created_at over @ribbits if you want a chronological feed, since it will be in order of buddies_ids at the end of my code.

Comment: In doing that, I believe I lost the ability to do `ribbit.user.username` in my view. Troubleshooting.